# Worst case delay in static CMOS

Tags: digital-logic, cmos

I'm trying to understand the worst-case delay path for this homework problem solution that I got wrong. The worst-case rising delay should be when either P2 & P4 or P3 & P5 are ON, but solution also includes NMOS transistors N3 & N5 as ON. I'm not able to understand as to why include NMOS as well. Could anyone help me with an explanation?

[image]

Comment: N3,N5 are OFF is not a worst case scenario; the worst case is when all the possible capacitances are being charged. With N3,N5 turned ON, NMOS internal capacitances are charged, stealing current from P2,P4 or P3,P5 branches.

Comment: @V.V.T Thanks for the reply. If that is the case, then why don't we consider one whole single branch of NMOS as well i.e., N1, N4 and N5.

Comment: You should avoid short-circuiting configurations that would create a non-zero, possibly great, DC (static) current.